# WP_Query infinite Loop

Tags: wp-query

I'm creating a short code to display a table based on a custom post type. For some reason this is creating an infinite loop. Here is the code for the shortcode

```
  function cwf_enquiry_table_html()
  {
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'form-enquiry'
    );

    $form_enquiries = new WP_Query($args);

    if($form_enquiries->have_posts())
    {
      while($form_enquiries->have_posts())
      {
        echo '<p>' . get_the_title() . '</p>';
      }
    }

    // wp_reset_query();
  }
  add_shortcode('enquiry_table', 'cwf_enquiry_table_html');
```

Currently this is just returning "Home" constantly. I've got the shortcode on the home page so I presume it's pulling some other query and not the one I am trying to run. As you can see I tried to reset the query but it didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `$form_enquiries->the_post()` to ["push" the loop onto the next post](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) - otherwise yes, you get an infinite loop!

```
while ( $form_enquiries->have_posts() ) {
    $form_enquiries->the_post();
    // rest of your loop
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was something obvious I was missing ... Marked as correct in case anyone else makes the same mistake.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Awesome thanks for point `$form_enquiries->the_post();`